# C# - efficient way to get and set multiple values in one property

Tags: c#, properties

I would like to get some advise about getting and setting multiple values in one property. I have a lot of the same properties that get and set an `int` value from app settings, based on a selected profile (so the value will be retrieved from the app settings in the getter and in the setter the new value will be saved to the app settings).

Currently, all properties look like the following example code:

```
public int NumberValue
{
    get 
    { 
        if (_profile == MainProfile.ProfileOne)
        {
            return AppSettings.NumberValue1; 
        }
        else if(_profile == MainProfile.ProfileTwo)
        {
            return AppSettings.NumberValue2; 
        }
        else
        {
            return AppSettings.NumberValue3;  
        }
    }
    set
    {
        if (_profile == MainProfile.ProfileOne)
        {
            AppSettings.NumberValue1 = value; 
        }
        else if(_profile == MainProfile.ProfileTwo)
        {
            AppSettings.NumberValue2 = value;
        }
        else
        {
            AppSettings.NumberValue3 = value; 
        }

        SaveAppSettings();
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is an efficient way to rewrite these properties in a more efficient way.

Comment: Have you thought about doing different classes? ``FooProfileOne``, ``FooProfileTwo``... with a base class of ``Foo`` or interface of ``IFoo`` ?

Comment: Why don't you consider using your own ConfigurationSection implementation? It would be much cleaner. You can also have a base class containing these properties and can have an extended class for each profile.

Comment: What exactly is `MainProfile` ? Is it an enum or a class ?

Comment: @fabjan it's a enum.

Comment: Btw, you know you could have your profiles in different config files and just load the relevent with ``ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("xxxx.config");`` ?

Comment: Store the values in private members and load and save them when _profile is changed.

Comment: @RandRandom thank you will try simulair solution.

Comment: One shouldn't really use properties for deciding which configuration should be used - it is a separate task that could be done elsewhere (in a method with change of architecture etc). Property is a part of a class and S from SOLID should be applied for it also. Generally speaking - It shouldn't have more than one responsibility (normally is is accessing data from a field or assigning new data to a field). Also I'd advise to use `switch` instead of `else if` in C# 7 switch has much more to offer.

Comment: @Fabjan Yes i read about that, i was indeed looking for a way with methods but i gues it will be cleaner with a new layer like discribed in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach could be to see your configuration more abstract. Implement a layer between your settings and business logic which will consume the values.
This layer should handle the profiles and returns what you need, instead of a lot if-else-switches in a property getter and setter, put them into an object.

The new layer could just be a `Configuration` object that needs a `MainProfile` on initialization and implements a `IConfiguration` interface that provides `GetNumberValue` and `SaveNumberValue` methods. The implementation of your `IConfiguration` will contain your logic you have in actual getter and setter methods.
Now this `Configuration` object could be used in your getter and setter instead of if-else-switches.

```
public interface IConfiguration
{
    int GetNumberValue();

    void SaveNumberValue(int number);
}
```

Based on the possible solution above, you could add a method `SetProfile` to the interface and decide in your logic for which profile the value should be stored or read.

It is also possible to create separate classes that will represent different `ConfigurationSections` in your `App.config` file or you create for each profile an own `App.config` file. Then the `Configuration` object could handle to load the necessary file.

Comment: Thanks @Chw, Indeed your solution was already mentioned in comments. I will mark this as answer anway because it will resolve my problems. :)